# Execute Anonymous Apex Timing Out in For Loop

Tags: apex

**Background**

Two previous fields on the Contact object that were formula fields referencing fields on the parent Account are now being "moved" to new text fields. Moving forward the value from the parent Account will be pushed to the Contact with a Process Builder. However, I need to ensure that for all existing Contact records the value from the parent Account is pushed as well.

**Current Solution**

Since this only needs to be run once, developed basic Apex to be run in the Developer Console Execute Anonymous window, which retrieves the Account data, retrieves the Contacts to be updated and then updates the Contacts with the Account data.

```
Map<ID,Account> accMap = new Map<ID, Account>([
SELECT Id, source_field1__c, source_field2__c
  FROM Account
  Where source_field1__c != null OR source_field1__c != null
]);

List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact>([
    SELECT Id, new_field1__c, new_field2__c
    FROM Contact
    WHERE Status__c = 'Active'
  ]);

for(Contact c:conList){
  c.new_field1__c = acctMap.get(c.AccountId).source_field1__c;
  c.new_field2__c = acctMap.get(c.AccountId).source_field2__c;
}
update conList;
```

**Issue**

Upon running this code n the Developer Console Execute Anonymous window the CPU limit is exceeded with error `Apex CPU time limit exceeded`

What's so inefficient with the code that's causing this time out? The queries themselves can run just fine, and the size of `conList` is only ~500 records.

Is there just a better overall solution then this Apex? Should I do an export/import of the records to invoke the Process Builder that will handle the push moving forward? Is that a better option in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Process Builder is already active, you can probably just do:

```
update [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE new_field1__c = null OR new_field2__c = null];
```

Note that you were using "!=", which would have affected all records that were *already* updated. Presumably, this was not your intent.

Or, if your Process Builder is on the Account (which I just realized it might be), you could probably also do:

```
update [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id IN 
     (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE new_field1__c = null or new_field2__c = null)];
```

---

Edit: Based on comments...

What I would do is limit the number of records used until the process succeeds, then repeat the script until no more records remain.

```
Integer x = 400;
Contact[] records = [
  SELECT Account.source_field1__c, Account.source_field2__c 
  FROM Contact 
  WHERE (new_field1__c = null or new_field2__c = null) and 
        Status__c = 'Active' and
        (Account.source_field1__c != null or Account.source_field2__c != null) 
  limit :x];
System.assert(records.size() != 0, 'No more records to process.');
for(Contact record: records) {
  record.new_field1__c = record.Account.source_field1__c;
  record.new_field2__c = record.Account.source_field2__c;
}
update records;
```

This should be more efficient than your current version, but will require multiple runs to complete successfully. The assertion is in place so that you can use the Ctrl-Alt-E hotkey combo; you'll get a popup message when all the records are processed. If you get a CPU timeout exception, reduce "x" until you stop getting the error.

Comment: As is, the Process Builder (which does run on Account) only triggers the push action when `source_field1__c` or `source_field2__c` changes. Thus when I "kick" the Account records from the update DML you provided, the push action in the Process Builder doesn't get triggered. Now I could update the criteria in the PB to remove the "field must be changed"  criteria but ideally, I leave it as is. Any other thoughts on workarounds or code optimization?

Comment: @John_Henry Added an optimized version, more suggestions. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: +1, @sfdcfox, just a side question is this requirement  not like a data loader scenario? where you extract the account,contact info update them and push the csv back to the system?

Comment: @RedDevil One could always choose to use the data loader, or even the Import Wizard. Some people (myself included) prefer to not do so because a script is usually more efficient, but if an ETL tool is your preferred method, you certainly could.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks Just clarified

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
Map<ID,Account> accMap = new Map<ID, Account>([
SELECT Id, source_field1__c, source_field2__c
  FROM Account
  WHERE source_field1__c != null OR source_field2__c != null]);

List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact>([
SELECT Id, new_field1__c, new_field2__c
FROM Contact
WHERE Status__c = 'Active' AND AccountId IN :accMap.keyset()]);

for(Contact c: conList){
  c.new_field1__c = accMap.get(c.AccountId).source_field1__c;
  c.new_field2__c = accMap.get(c.AccountId).source_field2__c;
}
update contacts;
```

Looks like in your WHERE clause for the Account, you had:

```
new_field1__c != null OR new_field2__c != null
```

I have changed it to:

```
source_field1__c != null OR source_field2__c != null
```

That could me wrong on my side!

Let me know if that worked :)

Comment: That's just a typo in the code, doesn't change the results